# Using Fork on Hardhat in testing

Tags: testing, hardhat

I am getting an error using a hardhat fork for testing.
I run the forked node with

"npx hardhat node --fork https://eth-mainnet.alchemyapi.io/v2/key --fork-block-number 13997235"

I am able to successfully query the node from a web3 application.
When I try to run tests with "npx hardhat test" it fails.

The test code is:

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers, waffle } = require("hardhat");
const provider = waffle.provider;


it("test getting contract data from fork", async function () {
    WETH9 = await ethers.getContractFactory('WETH9')
    const WETH_address = "0xC02aaA39b223FE8D0A0e5C4F27eAD9083C756Cc2"
    weth = await WETH9.attach(WETH_address)
    console.log("rweth: " + await weth.decimals()); 
    return true;
  })
```

The error is,

"Error: call revert exception (method="decimals()", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.5.0)"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Afaik `hardhat test` spins up their own test network, unless you specify it in the [hardhat config](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/guides/mainnet-forking.html).

Alternatively you should be able specify explicitly that hardhat should use your local hardhat node (e.g. `http://localhost:8545`) by adding `--network localhost`. See https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network/#running-stand-alone-in-order-to-support-wallets-and-other-software